# Bootstrap: Change "active" class to another "li" - Text carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, carousel

So i'm trying to make a text carousel with text indicators.
My text carousel change perfecly "active" class to an item to another.
But I can't seems to get my indicator ("nav") to change with the carousel his active class to one to another with jQuery.

Here's my HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div data="0" class="col-md-12">
                    <p>001</p>
                    <h2>TEST</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div data="1" class="col-md-12">
                    <p>002</p>
                    <h2>TEST</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>003</p>
                    <h2>TEST</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="carousel-nav">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#"><span style="letter-spacing:0.0px;">001</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:20px;">•</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEST</a></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#"><span style="letter-spacing:0.4px;">002</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:20px;">•</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEST</a></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#"><span style="letter-spacing:0.4px;">003</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="font-size:20px;">•</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's my jQuery

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel');
$carousel.carousel();
var handled=false;
var itemclicked="";
$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var current=$(e.target).find('.item.active');
    var indx=$(current).index();
    if((indx+2)>$('.carousel-nav li').length)
        indx=-1

     if(!handled)
     {
        $('.carousel-nav li').removeClass('active')
        $('.carousel-nav li:nth-child('+(indx+2)+')').addClass('active');

     }
     else
     {
        handled=!handled;
     }

});

$(".carousel-nav li").on('click',function(){
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
   handled=true;
});
```

Comment: You have two elements with the same ID of custom_carousel - you may find that changing one of those to something different and changing your JS that the problem disappears.

Comment: Did the change like you ask.
But I still can't see any improvement with the "active" matter.

Comment: And it looks like you changed your approach to the `slide.bs.carousel` event handling as well. It might help to use breakpoints to step through the code and verify the values are what you're hoping they will be. The `slide.bs.carousel` event does have ready-to-use information about the slide index about to be shown, so my advice is to try to use that information as directly as possible rather than calculating indexes from the DOM.